# modifier: in order not to be stolen

Tags: dangling-modifier

Is the following boldfaced part a dangling modifier? If it is, how would you fix it?

Tom kept his jewels in the safe **in order not to be stolen**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds as though Tom didn't want anyone to steal *him*!

You could say:

> ...in order that they should not be stolen.

or, less formally

> ...so they wouldn't be stolen.